# MYSQL Multiple INNER JOIN on one line

Tags: mysql, join

How can I create multiple INNER JOIN in one line for the sake of readability?
My redacted code right now looks like this:

```
SELECT
    FOO
FROM
    RAD_REL_USER_GROUP 
INNER JOIN 
    RAD_USER
INNER JOIN
    RAD_GROUP_INFO
INNER JOIN
    RAD_CHECK
INNER JOIN
    COM_CLIENT_PLAN
INNER JOIN
    COM_CLIENTS
ON
    FOO.COL = BAR.COL
```

Is there a way to include all the INNER JOINS in one line so it's easier to read?

Comment: Why don't you just remove all the `\n`? I guess your code would be easier to read than putting everything in one line.

Comment: Having all the `INNER JOIN` on the same line would make the code much more *difficult* to read; it would make the reader have to work *harder* to decipher the statement. (Removing the unnecessary keyword `INNER` would also make it easier to read, less clutter.) Without any join predicates, we might be inclined to include the keyword `CROSS` before `JOIN`, not because it has any affect, but as documentation to aid the reader. Also, qualifying column references (e.g. `foo`) with a table name or table alias would also make it *easier* for the reader to figure out which table that's coming from.

Comment: You're right. In terms of readability it looks okay the way it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there is some whitespace where it is needed MySQL doesn't care; but as others said in the comments, making it one line would not make it more readable. To me this is more readable

```
SELECT FOO
FROM RAD_REL_USER_GROUP 
   INNER JOIN RAD_USER
      /* ON really, you're joining everything to everything 
         AND this results in a "cross product"
      */ 
   INNER JOIN RAD_GROUP_INFO
   INNER JOIN RAD_CHECK
   INNER JOIN COM_CLIENT_PLAN
   INNER JOIN COM_CLIENTS ON FOO.COL = BAR.COL
```